# plotly - different colours for different surfaces

Tags: r, plotly

Using `plotly` I would like to have each surface to have different colour.

```
library(plotly)
t1 <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1); t2 <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1)

p1 <- matrix(nrow = length(t1), ncol = length(t2))
p2 <- matrix(nrow = length(t1), ncol = length(t2))

p8a1 <- 1.2
p8a2 <- 1
p8d <- -1
p8b1 <- 0.7
p8b2 <- 0.6

for (i in 1:length(t2)) {
   for (j in 1:length(t1)) {
      p1[i, j] <- 1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * (p8a1 * t1[j] + p8a2 * t2[i] + p8d)))
      p2[i, j] <- (1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * p8a1 * (t1[j]- p8b1)))) * 
                  (1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * p8a2 * (t2[j]- p8b2))))
   }
}

df1 <- list(t1, t2, p1)
df2 <- list(t1, t2, p2)

names(df1) <- c("t1", "t2", "p1")
names(df2) <- c("t1", "t2", "p2")
m <- list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 5, t = 0, pad = 3)

p <- plot_ly(color = c("red", "blue")) %>%
     add_surface(x = df1$t1,
                 y = df1$t2,
                 z = df1$p1,
                 opacity = 0.8) %>%
     add_surface(x = df2$t1,
                 y = df2$t2,
                 z = df2$p2,
                 opacity = 1) %>%
     layout(autosize = F, width = 550, height = 550, margin = m,
            scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Theta 1"),
                         yaxis = list(title = "Theta 2"),
                         zaxis = list(title = "P")),
            dragmode = "turntable")
p
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to change colours of these two surfaces. I tried to add `color = I("red")` and `color = I("blue")` arguments into `add_surface` but this just changed colour scale from red to blue for both surfaces.

I also tried to add `color = "red"` into `plot_ly()` and add `inherit = F` into second `add_surface`. This changed the first surface only, but only the yellow default color into red. I would love to have one surface red and second one blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds trivial but it's a bit tricky in Plotly. The color of a surface plot is either derived from the z values or from an array with the same dimensions as z. This color array only accepts numerical values, no color strings or RGB values.

So let's define an array for our colors

```
color <- rep(0, length(df1$p1))
dim(color) <- dim(df1$p1)
```

Next we need to trick Plotly into ignoring the colorscale.

```
surfacecolor=color,
             cauto=F,
             cmax=1,
             cmin=0
```

et voilà, we have a uniformely colored plot.

[image]

---

```
library(plotly)
t1 <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1); t2 <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1)

p1 <- matrix(nrow = length(t1), ncol = length(t2))
p2 <- matrix(nrow = length(t1), ncol = length(t2))

p8a1 <- 1.2
p8a2 <- 1
p8d <- -1
p8b1 <- 0.7
p8b2 <- 0.6

for (i in 1:length(t2)) {
  for (j in 1:length(t1)) {
    p1[i, j] <- 1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * (p8a1 * t1[j] + p8a2 * t2[i] + p8d)))
    p2[i, j] <- (1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * p8a1 * (t1[j]- p8b1)))) * 
      (1 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * p8a2 * (t2[j]- p8b2))))
  }
}

df1 <- list(t1, t2, p1)
df2 <- list(t1, t2, p2)

names(df1) <- c("t1", "t2", "p1")
names(df2) <- c("t1", "t2", "p2")
m <- list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 5, t = 0, pad = 3)

color <- rep(0, length(df1$p1))
dim(color) <- dim(df1$p1)
p <- plot_ly(colors = c('red', 'blue')) %>%
  add_surface(x = df1$t1,
              y = df1$t2,
              z = df1$p1,
              opacity = 0.8,
              #surfacecolor=c('red')
              surfacecolor=color,
              cauto=F,
              cmax=1,
              cmin=0
  )
color2 <- rep(1, length(df2$p2))
dim(color2) <- dim(df2$p2 )

p <-  add_surface(p,
              x = df2$t1,
              y = df2$t2,
              z = df2$p2,
              opacity = 1,
              surfacecolor=color2,
              cauto=F,
              cmax=1,
              cmin=0)
p
```

Comment: Well, this was a little bit tricky! Thank you very much, it works perfectly!