# R plotly - Different colorscales for two scatter on the same plots

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm trying to plot two different set of data on the same figure, using two `àdd_trace` commands. I specify a different colorscales for each, but the second one is ignored , so my second scatter plot has the same color gradient than the first one. How can I fix this ?

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608754/plotly-different-color-scales-for-multiple-surfaces), but it doesn't work (I got a warning saying `'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'colorscale'`).

My code (with a dataframe with random numbers for testing) :

```
library(plotly)
library(FactoMineR)

n <- 10 ; m <- 20 ; reps <- 6 
a <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(m), n, m/n), 
                         replicate(reps, sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE))))

res.pca = PCA(a, scale.unit=TRUE, graph=F, axes=c(1,2))
ind <- as.data.frame(res.pca$ind$coord)
cos2 <- as.data.frame(res.pca$ind$cos2)
var <- as.data.frame(res.pca$var$coord)
cos2_v <- as.data.frame(res.pca$var$cos2)

biplot <- plot_ly(ind) %>%
  add_trace(x=ind[,1],
            y=ind[,2],
            type='scatter',
            text=rownames(a),
            textposition='top',
            mode="markers+text", 
            color=cos2[,1],
            colors="OrRd",
            marker=list(symbol=27, size=11)) %>%
  add_trace(var, 
            x=var[,1], 
            y=var[,2],
            type = 'scatter',
            text=colnames(a),
            textposition='top',
            mode="markers+text", 
            color=cos2_v[,1],
            colors="BuGn",
            marker=list(symbol=4, size=11))
```

Thanks in advance (the actual result is on the picture below).

[image]

Comment: Please help ! I'm stuck ! :)

Answer (score 2):

This works. If you do something custom you have to format the arguments according to `plotly::schema()`. The `colors` argument in plotly is a helper to streamline the more complicated `plotly.js` syntax. Note how `color` and all the other marker arguments have to be within a list called `marker`, under which you have to manually format both the `colorscale` (to get the colors you want) and the `colorbar` (to get the colorscale positioned correctly). Note also that the legend is for the shape, while the colorscale is for the color (confusingly the colorscale is not the legend).

```
library(plotly)
library(FactoMineR)

n <- 10 ; m <- 20 ; reps <- 6
a <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(m), n, m/n),
                         replicate(reps, sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE))))

res.pca = PCA(a, scale.unit=TRUE, graph=F, axes=c(1,2))
ind <- as.data.frame(res.pca$ind$coord)
cos2 <- as.data.frame(res.pca$ind$cos2)
var <- as.data.frame(res.pca$var$coord)
cos2_v <- as.data.frame(res.pca$var$cos2)

biplot <- plot_ly(ind,showlegend=F) %>%
  add_trace(x=ind[,1],
            y=ind[,2],
            type='scatter',
            text=rownames(a),
            textposition='top',
            mode="markers+text",
            marker=list(symbol=27, size=11
                        ,color=cos2[,1]
                        ,colorscale=list(
                          list(0,RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'OrRd')[1])
                          ,list(1,RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'OrRd')[3])
                        )
                        ,colorbar=list(yanchor='bottom',len=.5)
            )) %>%
  add_trace(x=var[,1],
            y=var[,2],
            type='scatter',
            text=colnames(a),
            textposition='top',
            mode="markers+text",
            marker=list(symbol=4, size=11
                        ,color=cos2_v[,1]
                        ,colorscale=list(
                          list(0,RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'BuGn')[1])
                          ,list(1,RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'BuGn')[3])
                        )
                        ,colorbar=list(yanchor='top',len=.5)
            ))
biplot
```

[result with two colorscales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uelZk.png)