# R: "Coloring" plotly plots according to another variable

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to replicate the answer provided in this Stack Overflow post over here: [Color surface by variable with plotly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537977/color-surface-by-variable-with-plotly-in-r)

Suppose I have the following "data frame" ("my_grid"):

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

#create grid and evaluate function
input_1 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_2 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_3 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_4 <- seq(0,100,1)

my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4)
my_grid$final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 + input_4
```

We can see how this data frame looks like:

```
head(my_grid)

  input_1 input_2 input_3 input_4 final_value
1       0       0       0       0    1.000000
2       1       1       1       1    3.381773
3       2       2       2       2    4.493151
4       3       3       3       3    5.151128
5       4       4       4       4    6.589554
6       5       5       5       5    9.324738
```

****Question:**** I want to make a 3D surface plot with variables "input_1", "input_2", "input_3" - And then color the surface according to "final_value"

```
       plot_ly() %>% 
            add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$input_3, type="mesh3d" )
 %>%   add_surface(surfacecolor = my_grid$final_value,
                  cauto=F,
                  cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
                  cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
      )
```

But this returns several errors, such as:

- `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"`
- `Error: unexpected ',' in "                  cauto=F,"`

I have tried different ways to debug this code, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone please show me how to fix these errors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply...i am more familiar with data frames and less familiar with matrices... still trying to figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150158/plotly-different-colours-for-different-surfaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some of your `syntax` and added `z = my_grid %>% as.matrix()` to your code, and it works as intended now. See below,

```
plot_ly() %>% 
        add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$input_3, type='mesh3d') %>%
        add_surface(
                z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
                surfacecolor = my_grid,
                cauto=F,
                cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
                cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
        )
```

Your first error were the following,

```
foo()
%>% bar()
```

In order for the `%>%` to work as intended, it has to be inline of ending parenthesis.

When the `syntax` were corrected, I got the `Error: 'z' must be a numeric matrix`. And therefore I added `z = my_grid %>% as.matrix()`.

---

### [image]

**Note:** If it still doesn't work as intended, please post your `sessionInfo()`, as the code worked for me after `syntax` correction and addition of `arguments.`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! In the above graph, x = input_1, y = input_2 and z = input_3? If you zoom into this picture here : https://imgur.com/a/VruwFPg , you will see a point where x = 4, y = 100 and z = 200.356 . In the original data ("my_grid"), this point does not exist. Is there a reason why this point is appearing? Also, is it possible to include "my_value" in the hover text? thank you so much for all your help!